# Radio Button Text Alignment to left in Flutter

Tags: flutter, radio-button

I want to create a Radio Button using Flutter in VS Code. I've done the radio button with functionality but the requirement of my project is to align the radio button text to the left side. But I can't to do that. Here I attached my sample source code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      // Hide the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: '',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // The inital group value
  String _selectedGender = 'male';
  String text = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          '',
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xffbcbcbc))),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  leading: Radio(
                    fillColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                        (states) => Color(0xfff29257)),
                    value: 'Male',
                    groupValue: _selectedGender,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedGender = value!.toString();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  title: const Text('Male'),
                  textColor: Colors.grey,
                  focusColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                      (states) => Color(0xfff29257)),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Radio(
                    fillColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                        (states) => Color(0xfff29257)),
                    value: 'female',
                    groupValue: _selectedGender,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedGender = value!.toString();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  title: const Text('Female'),
                  textColor: Colors.grey,
                  //fillColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.green),
                  focusColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                      (states) => Color(0xfff29257)),
                ),
                
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to customize those radio buttons?

Comment: mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start to column widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler approach would be to use the [RadioListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RadioListTile-class.html) widget and set controlAffinity = ListTileControlAffinity.trailing. This will move the text to the left and the radio button to the right:

```
           RadioListTile(
              value: true,
              groupValue: groupVal,
              onChanged: (val) {},
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
            )
```

Comment: It working fine. Thanks. But I cant to set up fillcolor  property to the RadioListTile. I want to change Radio button color which is in Active or not Active. Can you please sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For left text alignment you can use RadioListTile property

```
controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
```